# How to change time zone of error log file of MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have set time zone of MySQL in my.ini:
`default_time_zone='+8:00'`
but the time zone of log info in the /Data/**.err seems still to be '+0:00':
`2016-02-01T02:40:49.087562Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: ……`
actually it was 2016-02-01 10:40.
how can i change the time zone of log info in the error log file. 
Thanks.

Comment: As of MySQL 5.7.2, the log_timestamps system variable controls the timestamp time zone of messages written to the error log (as well as to general query log and slow query log files). Permitted values are UTC (the default) and SYSTEM (local system time zone). Before MySQL 5.7.2, messages use the local system time zone http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_timestamps

Comment: Thanks very much,  i've set `log_timestamps = SYSTEM`(MySQL5.7.9), it works now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.7.2, the log_timestamps system variable controls the timestamp time zone of messages written to the error log (as well as to general query log and slow query log files). Permitted values are UTC (the default) and SYSTEM (local system time zone). Before MySQL 5.7.2, messages use the local system time zone

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_timestamps

Comment: This is very informative but even too informative @MTK below gave simple yet useful answer.

Answer (score 23):

In my.ini or my.cnf (according to your mysql configuration file) under [mysqld]

```
[mysqld]
log_timestamps = SYSTEM
```

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/timestamps_system.cnf` Rather than add to an existing file that could conceivably get overwritten, I put these lines in a new file.

Answer (score -3):

set default timezone in your code.

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');